# concerns about xss attacks in url $_GET submissions

Tags: php, xss

Ok. Last week I suffered an XSS attack and SQL injection by a competitor forum....

1) I realized I wasnt using a prepared statement (I use PDO) in an small ajax function in the register.php page, that retrieves if the user exists or not... now fixed, it was `user=`"$user"`....direct...ok.

2) I wasnt using CSRF tokens at all, now I have put csrf tokens, in all the submitted forms that use the structure `<form></form>`

3) I output now with `htmlentities()`

4) I validate the inputs

**I want to know the next**

Do I need to sanitize every $_GET[""] used in the pages urls,
of the paginations numbers buttons? `p=$_GET["page"]`
they dont have access to the database, they are just `$_GET` used for pagination, but I have read, that I can be vulnerable to XSS, if I have a `$_GET` open and unsanitized...

Please, I need to know in order to avoid overconcerns about the vulnerabilities to xss, or to know if to implementing a sanitation of those `$_GET` is not important thank you.

Comment: You should sanitize not the input but the output

Comment: so I need to sanitize all the outputs of every `$_GET` used in paginations numbers? regarding they dont have acces to the database?

Comment: Why only GET and why only paginations?

Comment: $_GET in the pages urls are the most common $_GET in my site. I need to know if I need to clean it them up

Comment: It's hard to tell. If you can be absolutely sure, that even the most malicious value in a GET (or POST / PUT / ...) parameter will not lead to anything serious, you can possibly omit sanitizing. But (when) can you be really? It's a good practice to regard ANY data from the client als potentially bad and sanitize them / check the for data type, length, correctness...

Answer (score 1):

xss happens when a user tries to input 'something' on the web. I think the steps you used are correct, but for more security, maybe you should validate each $ _GET input with functions, maybe like this

```
    <?php

    function xss_clean($inputs = ''){
        $regex      = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/";
        $inputs     = preg_replace($regex, "", $inputs);

        return $inputs;
    }

    //For Example
    $some_input     = isset($_GET['username'])?xss_clean($_GET['username']):'';

    ?>
```

you can change regex according to your needs

Comment: ok, thank you. what if I vaildat it as a `INT`? because they are only numbers

Comment: you're welcome. you can change regex to $regex = "/[^0-9]/";

Comment: ok, thank you, but why would I need to validate $_GET that are only structural and are not linked to the database?